# How to retrieve model declared on Razor view using ControllerContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I am writing custom DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider and overriding method

```
 GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, 
               ControllerContext context, 
               IEnumerable<Attribute>  attributes)
```

How can I figure out what is the name of model type that is declared in Razor view that this context is accessing?

Comment: You better rely on the model *type* rather than on the model name.

Answer (score 0):

To get the model from ControllerContext use:

```
var model = context.Controller.ViewData.Model;
var modelName = model.ToString();
```

Note: You should use model type instead of the string, so use:

```
if (model is MyViewModel) { //... }
```

instead of

```
if (modelName == "MyViewModel") { //... }
```